# btmp is showing me a login duration over an hour. How can a failed login last that long?

Tags: login, hacking

I was watching a server console for results of my own activity and was bombarded by someone trying to do GET on a long alphabetical list of files/directories. I checked lastb and found some entries that I don't understand.

```
telecoma ssh:notty    85.209.11.227    Mon Jan 29 14:00 - 14:27  (00:26)
telecoma ssh:notty    85.209.11.227    Mon Jan 29 14:00 - 14:00  (00:00)
root     ssh:notty    85.209.11.227    Mon Jan 29 12:34 - 14:00  (01:25)
```

If these are failed logins, how can that bottom one have lasted for an hour and 25 minutes? Does the log collect up a whole series of attempts from the same user and just store one log? If so, how close together do the attempts have to be in order to be grouped, since, for instance, the first pair of logs look like they could be grouped?

If this is the case is there a tool that would tell me how many attempts were actually made by that user?